# Attaching an existing table to another table

Tags: c++, c, lua, lua-table

If I use `lua_getfield()` and read a table from an already existing table, how can I add this table to another table? As far as I understand, this "adding" will be a "referencing" instead of a real copy, right?

Comment: Yes, if you assign that value into the other table you will have a reference to the original table and not a copy of the table. If you need a copy of the table you get to copy it manually.

Comment: ok. but how do I add the table to an existing one? In the following example I just wanted to duplicate to the same table, but it does not work. I assume there might be something else missing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In fact, it is rather involved to create a copy of table.

A table doesn't have an owner. You only ever have references; You can have as many as you copy around. When there are none accessible to the garbage collector, the table is eligible for deletion. (The same goes for function values.)